# Adding up rows to get totals per table

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a page here: http://myechef.wpengine.com/menus/italian-menu/ with multiple tables on. Each table has rows of dishes with a price next to them (literally a menu).

What I need to do is add up the prices column for each table and give a total for that table (aka course) underneath using Javascript but I'm struggling.

I can do this by giving each table a unique ID but that is a very long way of doing things because this page is content manageable and therefore there could be 20 tables, or only 2. There is no way to know in advance.

I'm sure there must be a simple way to create a function that just adds up the prices in each table. Does anyone have any ideas?

This is what I have so far. Its a bit easier to follow in jsfiddle than the actual page: https://jsfiddle.net/hxt3s5uh/

I'm pretty sure I have to do an .each(function()) for each course first, then inside that, loop through each row of the table to work out the price of the dish (this bit works on my live example) and then add up all prices for that table, which is where I get stuck. It seems to always add up all rows on the page. The live page currently adds up all prices and then multiplies it by 3 because there are 3 tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var total_value = 0,
    total_average = 0;

function calculate_dish_totals() {


    $('.menu-builder tbody tr').each(function () {

        var $cell = $(this).find('td:first-child'),
            $cell2 = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)'),
            $row = $cell.closest('tr'),
            price = $cell.data('cost');
        servings = $cell2.data('servings');

        if (!price) {
            price = 0
        }

        if (isNaN(servings) || servings < 1) {
            servings = 1
        }

        //console.log(servings);
        singleprice = price / servings;

        // Display the price for the dish in the last column
        $row.find('.price').html(singleprice.toFixed(2));

        // Add up each price
        total_value += singleprice;

    });

    // divide by total row count to find the average cost
    var $av_cell = $('.course-totals tbody tr.average td:nth-child(2)'),
        average_count = $av_cell.data('count');

    total_average = total_value / average_count;
    console.log(total_value);
    console.log(average_count);

    $('.js-course-total-price').html(total_value.toFixed(2));
    $('.js-course-average-price').html(total_average.toFixed(2));

}

// course-totals is a wrapper for each list of dishes and the totals
$('.course-tables').each(function () {
    calculate_dish_totals()
});
```

Comment: Why don't you give a class instead of an id, request all the tab with this class, then sum them? PS: `reduce` looks more appropriate than `forEach` for sums.

Comment: Do you really need to do this using javascript? As I can see in your site this content is static (won't change by any DOM event) so you can render it already calculated from the server side (I'm asuming you are using PHP, since most of your content is from wordpress plugins).

Answer (score 1):

You're very close to a solution! With your current approach, you're correct in assuming you need to iterate through the tables using `.each()`. However, you're currently iterating through the results returned by the selector:

```
$('.menu-builder tbody tr')
```

This gives you all the `<tr>` elements contained within every `.menu-builder` table, so when you calculate the total and average prices, it will always be the total/average price of every dish on the page.

You'll need to first select the tables with `$(".menu-builder")`, and only then iterate through each of their child `<tr>` elements using `.find('tbody tr')`. This way, you can restrict calculations of total/average price to only dishes contained within the current table.

With some slight modifications to your code, the changed parts of `calculate_dish_totals()` will be:

```
function calculate_dish_totals() {

    $(".menu-builder").each(function(){
        $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function () {

            // [...]

        });

        // [...]

        $(this).next().find('.js-course-total-price').html(total_value.toFixed(2));
        $(this).next().find('.js-course-average-price').html(total_average.toFixed(2));

    });

}
```

With this change, there's also no need to call `calculate_dish_totals()` for each `.course-tables` - meaning it can now be called with simply:

```
// $('.course-tables').each(function () {
    calculate_dish_totals()
// });
```

Here's an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hxt3s5uh/4/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

*Note: This assumes that the next table after a dish table will always be the corresponding total/average price table. If this isn't the case, let me know and I'll adjust the answer accordingly.*

Comment: Hi Serlite, I'm really pleased to know I'm not that far away from a solution! :) 

I had a look at this and its still not quite right. In JSFiddle the solution still adds up all tables but then multiplies them by the number of tables. Thats why table two had a total of £28.40 when it should have been £8.25. 

I removed the '$('.course-tables').each(function () {' leaving only 'calculate_dish_totals()' which is closer again. Table one is now right but table two shows £14.20 when it should be a total of £8.25. I've updated JS Fiddle again with this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hxt3s5uh/4/)

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right! I definitely missed that you were already calling `calculate_dish_totals()` for each `.course-table`. Will update my answer accordingly so it's not left wrong. Glad I could help out, anyways!